How to drive a 7-segment LCD that has no common anode / cathode using a Raspberry Pico?
I recently acquired a 7-segment LCD, and I am having trouble to understand how to use it. Is it possible to use it with a Pico without any additional hardware?
From what I know from my research, LCDs need to be powered with AC, but as this specific display has no COM pins, multiplexing is not possible.
I am a beginner at electronics, trying to get a sense of things.
Display in question.
Datasheet.

It's relatively easy to drive since it's a static drive display. Pin 24 is BP (Backplane). According to the Datenblatt you linked:

It needs to be driven with AC with very little (<50mV) of DC component or you can permanently damage the display due to electrolytic action. They suggest 30Hz.
So you'd need to ensure the the segment and backplane waveforms occur very close in timing. You can drive them in phase for 'off' and out of phase for 'on'. Do not hold either segment or backplane in high or low state for long term (more than some dozens of microseconds) unless all pins going to the display are in the same state (all high or all low).
They can be driven directly from (otherwise unloaded) CMOS push-pull outputs since they will swing from GND to Vdd with virtually no offset.
Or you could buy a controller IC and use that. Here is another (I2C).


It needs to be driven with AC with very little (<50mV) of DC component. Does that mean i am simulting ac by switch between high and low with 50mV? Because the data sheet also mentions an operating voltage of 3V.


Drive the BP with a continuous 30Hz square wave 50% duty cycle between 0 and 3.3V. Drive each segment with an in-phase square wave for 'off' and inverted for 'on'. So the voltage from segment to BP will be 0V or 3.3V peak. At 30Hz you don't have to switch all the lines exactly at the same time to avoid 50mV of DC, but it might be best to do it in a hardware timer interrupt service routine rather than something like an RTOS task.

You could make your own parallel input controller with half a dozen 74HC86 quad Ex-or gates and a square wave source but that would be a lot less elegant than doing it in software.
